# What property of $n$ does this test?

Tags: data-analysis

I have the following sample data:

```
1       true
3       false
12      false
10      true
7       true
9       false
8       false
```

My question is, what property of $n$ does this test?

I have tried several things like prime number, composite number, happy number, etc., but nothing seems to fit the test cases. Can anybody help me?

Comment: $n=1 \vee n=10 \vee n=7$.

Comment: $n\neq3 \wedge n\neq12 \wedge n\neq9 \wedge n\neq8$.

Comment: @barakmanos that will be just for the data i posted but I have limited that there is a lot more data that I am working on, So I had to check what was the property and it was congruent modulo as answered by Peter.

Comment: Unless you post that other data, both comments above are eligible answers (and there are plenty more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is $$n\equiv 1\ (\mod\ 3\ )$$

Answer (score 1):

There can be many answers to this, even as simple as:

Is $n$ a root of $n^3-18n^2+87n-70$?

or

Does $n$ divide $70$?